# Order by date and field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have `SELECT` query with `LEFT JOINT (SELECT)` and order by `COALESCE(SELECT2.date, SELECT1.date)` but i need to order it too with `important` field.

So: if row have `important = 1` it need to be first, then `important = 0` but ordered by coleasce date so as so. Is this even posible?

Comment: Some sample data / structure would go a long way in seeing what you have, and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to order query by: important on top AND COALESCE(SELECT2.date, SELECT1.date) it's everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the `important` column first in the `order by` list.  Sorting `desc` (for descending) will place 1 before 0:

```
order by
        important DESC
,       coalesce(select2.date, select1.date)
```

You can even use `case` to sort the `important` column in a custom way:

```
order by
        case
        when important = 'SENATOR' then 1
        when important = 'PATRICIAN' then 2
        when important = 'PLEBS' then 3
        else 4
        end
,       coalesce(select2.date, select1.date)
```